Extracting CPU Vendor Name via cpuid on qemu-XV6 returns "Genuntelntel" on my AMD machine
I am running xv6 via QEMU on Ubuntu 20.04.6 via Windows WSL. I wanted to write a syscall to extract and print the CPU vendor name by editing the kernel code. Did the usual pleasantries, wrote up a function that was successfully implemented as a syscall within xv6
I then edited the function to print the CPU vendor name, only to get the most perplexing of results
// within sysproc.c
#include "types.h"
#include "x86.h"
#include "defs.h"
#include "proc.h"

int sys_cpuvendor(void) 
{
    char *buf;
    if(argptr(0, &buf, 13) < 0) //take a 13 element buffer to write the results into
        return -1;

    unsigned int ebx, ecx, edx;
    asm volatile (
        "mov $0, %%eax; \n"
        "cpuid; \n"
        "mov %%ebx, %0; \n"
        "mov %%edx, %1; \n"
        "mov %%ecx, %2; \n"
        : "=r"(ebx), "=r"(edx), "=r"(ecx)
        :
        : "%eax"
    );

//run cpuid via asm magic and write the results into registers, and finally into buf

    ((unsigned int*)buf)[0] = ebx;
    ((unsigned int*)buf)[1] = edx;
    ((unsigned int*)buf)[2] = ecx;
    buf[12] = '\0'; 

    return 0;
}

Here is the program that uses the syscall
int main(void) 
{


    char vendBuf[255];
    printf(1, "Printing device info with deviceInfo() call: ");
    deviceInfo(vendBuf);
    printf(1, "CPU Vendor Name: %s\n", vendBuf);
    exit();
 }

Running this function and printing the buffer it writes to gives me a strange result. The output is Genuntelntel, with the typo. The funny part is I am working on an AMD Ryzen machine? How and why did it get the CPU vendor wrong entirely, let alone the typo?

VMs don't normally give you direct access to the hardware from the VM (though you can configure direct access to a certain degree). What you're seeing is the emulated CPU.

@Ouroborus What would cause the typo though? Or is Genuntelntel deliberately set as the vendor name of the emulated cpu by the devs of QEMU?

As to why, I'm not sure. Maybe corruption in the Qemu exe? (I've heard one can add additional CPU configurations by modifying and recompiling it.) For me, Google Search only sees this question when searching "Genuntelntel" with quotes so it seems like a unique-to-you kind of problem.
